# How to fix this event related error in VB.net (windows phone 7)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, event-handling

Hi The following code gives me an error, which I am not too sure about how to fix. Can anyone help please?

Code:

```
    Public Event hw As EventHandler

Private Sub view_hw(sender As Object, eventArgs As Object)
    If hw IsNot Nothing Then
        hw.Invoke(Me, New EventArgs())
    End If
End Sub
```

Error:

```
Error   1   'Public Event hw(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Event hw As EventHandler

Private Sub view_hw(sender As Object, eventArgs As Object)
    RaiseEvent hw(Me, New EventArgs())
End Sub
```

Comment: If hw IsNot Nothing Then - 
 This line still gives me an error mentioned above

Comment: Think that `If hw IsNot Nothing Then` is not needed in vb.net, `RaiseEvent` treats that part!